# Only apply class to element if two arrays match index and also match name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of posible timeslots being rendered as p tags via mapping

```
{times.map((time, i) => (
    <p
      onClick={() => chooseTime(time, name)}
      className={`tc pa2 dib pointer ${colorClass(i)}`}
    >
      {time. dateUTCString}
    </p>
))}
```

The timeslots look something like this:

```
   "times": [
      {
        "timestamp": 1474607824073,
        "dateUTCString": "Sat Sep 03 2016 19:01:09 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
      },
      {
        "timestamp": 1389120349942,
        "dateUTCString": "Mon Aug 19 2019 05:43:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
      },
    etc...
```

I also have a state that is a fixed array that holds either a name of a company or null, and this gets updated as I click on a timeslot, and if i clicked on timeslot two, and I was in company two, it adds the name of that company to index two, so it matches the timeslot, something like this:

```
[
null,
company2,
null,
null,
etc...
]
```

The timeslots elements has a class which is a function that determines what should the class value should be, and to that class function, i pass it the index the element holds, as it is being render with by mapping over the timeslots array.

```
  const colorClass = (indexOfSelectedSlot) => {
    let color = 'black'
    selectedCompanies.forEach((companyName, id) => {
      if (indexOfSelectedSlot === id) {
      color = 'gray'
        if (name === companyName) {
          color = 'red'
        }
      }
    })
    return color
  }
```

Here is the full code in codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-hypatia-ew1vh?fontsize=14

So what i want to achive is this:

If i click on the first timeslot on company1, I want the first timeslot to be red, and the first timeslots on the other companies gray(as one person canno be in two places at the same time)

And leave the rest of the timeslots as they by default, black.

But now, if i press a timeslot, it gets red, but ALL the other slots turn gray.

Any idea how to fix this?

Here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-hypatia-ew1vh?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

You have the following code in companyPanel.js

```
  const colorClass = indexOfSelectedSlot => {
    let color = "black";
    selectedCompanies.forEach((companyName, id) => {
      if (indexOfSelectedSlot === id) {
        color = "gray";
        if (name === companyName) {
          color = "red";
        }
      }
    });
    return color;
  };
```

Change `color = "gray";` `to color = "black";` to keep the text black after clicking!

Comment: that just makes everything gray from the beggining, I want them to be black at the beggining, red if it was the clicked one, and gray if they are the same timeslot but in another company(like horizontally if you see the codesandbox)